# How to find specific vector images, like this one?

Tags: vector, stock-images

I wanted to know the place where I can find a vector. This small animal hand symbol is used in the image below. (after the name *Ed Sheeran*)

[image: The Small Hand Symbol/Vector]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That particular item is part of Photoshop's Default Shapes set.

[image: paw]

Simply select the Custom Shape Tool in Photoshop, then Select the shape from the menu on the Control Bar.

Comment: "that particular item" ...it is a paw shape, but not the same one, so _that particular_ shape can't be found in photoshops default shapes.

Answer (score 0):

To search for vector images in general, in advanced search settings, Google Image search has an option to search by file type. Choosing 'SVG' will find vector images ([example](http://www.google.co.uk/search?as_st=y&tbm=isch&hl=en&as_q=paw&as_epq=&as_oq=&as_eq=&cr=&as_sitesearch=&safe=off&orq=&tbs=ift%3asvg&biw=1366&bih=666&sei=8HgKULn7DubC0QXlkoHtCg)). Don't forget that normal copyright laws etc still apply, and that the preview images Google show aren't vector, only the full size orignal is.

For images as simple as this one though, you could create it faster than you could find one that is okay to use. If you don't have software and skills already, Inkscape is a free vector image program, and there's loads of tutorials on how to use it - all you need for a simple solid colour shape like this is ellipses and the pen tool.