# Creating underlines in callygraphy style

Tags: svg

I am not very familiar with graphic illustration. I want to create some underline samples like in this example, maybe a little more understated:

[image]

I have no Photoshop and I can't find any good samples via google (since I don't even know an exact term which describes what I want). Are there any good samples around? Best would be in SVG format.

Comment: You can [search for SVG files specifically using Google Image search](http://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/a/8548/3327), although your best bet is probably ornament fonts as Chris B suggests, [brushes](http://www.brusheezy.com/brushes/12719-calligraphic-ornament-brush-pack/premium), or [downloadable packs of eps files](http://www.vecteezy.com/ornaments/12669-calligraphic-ornament-vector-pack-/premium)

Answer (score 3):

These are calligraphy ornaments and flourishes that you can create in either vector (Illustrator) or type design software. Photoshop cannot produce this.

A great resource to find these are [Myfonts](http://www.myfonts.com/search/ornaments/) (search ornaments) or search google for "vector (or svg) ornaments".

Comment: +1, but it's worth being specific that it's SVG and true vector files that Photoshop can't produce - people sometimes add ornaments to raster images using the Photoshop pen tool, but Illustrator is more suitable if it's available.